# How can I enable a screen blanker (screensaver) for Ubuntu 17.10 Server console?

Tags: server, 17.10, screensaver, console

How can I enable a console blanker (screensaver) for Ubuntu 17.10 Server console?

Comment: Do you want the display switched to standby (to save power and lifetime) and/or lock the console session to prevent unauthorised access?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am trying to do.

Comment: (1) I asked an "or" question and it would help if you told us which one(s) of the given alternatives you mean. (2) Could you please [edit] your post when you want to clarify something or add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.